# ms-word:ofe|u|{url} Does not work in an email body of Graph SendMailPostRequestBody

Tags: hyperlink, microsoft-graph-api

Using JavaScript, writing ms-word:ofe|u|

```
<a href=ms-word:ofe|u|{item.fileUrl)} target={'_blank'} rel="noreferrer" >{item.FileName}</a>
```

The user can click the link on the page and the document opens in MS-Word.

Doing the same in an email body (ContentType = BodyType.Html), just writs the name and there is no link.
Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: How is this related to the Graph API? Could you provide more details? More code related to the Graph API.

Comment: The HTML is included as body inside a graph SendMailPostRequestBody type

Comment: Please include how do you set Content of the email body. Similar code works fine for me, so it's hard to reproduce the issue. Btw. what if you remove the bracket `)` from `{item.fileUrl)}` => `{item.fileUrl}`

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new();
 foreach (var link in jobFileLinks)
 {
    sb.Append($"<a href='$ms-word:ofe|u|{link.ItemLink}'>{link.FileName}</a><br/>");
 }
 var clickLink = $"<a href='{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LinkToDraftDone") + "?Job=" + message.JobNumber}' >Click here to notify me </a>";
 var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
 {
     Message = new Message
     {
         Subject = $"Job {message.JobNumber}: Please Return Draft {message.Action}",
         Body = new ItemBody
         {
             ContentType = BodyType.Html

Comment: Content = $"<p> Hi,<br/><br/>" +
                 $"Please review this draft. Answer any questions and/or note your approval in the file(s) below.<br/><br/>" +
                 $"[{message.DPCNotes}]<br/><br/>" +
                 $"1. Click the link(s) below to open the file(s).<br/>" +
                 $"{sb}<br/><br/>" +
                 $"2. After you’ve finished reviewing, save and close the file(s).<br/><br/>" +
                 $"3. Click <a href='{LinkToDraftDone + "?Job=" + message.JobNumber}' > here </a> to notify me that you’re done reviewing.<br/>" +

Comment: $"Thanks!<br/><p>"
         },
         ToRecipients = [new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = message.ConsultantLogin, }, },]
     }
 };
 await graphClient.Users[message.DPCLogin].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);

item.fileUrl) was a typo here
code works fine for  link in an email?.In a web page it works fine.